# Double click a Button before it does action

Tags: java, button, listener

I have a button whose function is executed by an actionListener. I would like the user to press the button twice with a corresponding message: "Do you really want to press the button?" How can I include such a check in my if-condition before the actionListener?

```
if (c_Button_Test.isPressed(request)) {      
  listener.actionBefore(new PrEvent(viewId
        , PrTestConstants.ID_CONTROL_OPEN_TEST
        , PrConstants.ID_EVENT_ACTION));
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Just remember the state of the clicking and react accordingly in your actionListener.

Comment: you can use an int and increase it everytime button is clicked. When int=2, do what you want and set the int 0 again.